# $location return path with not replaced named parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to get page ID from route parameter, so additional data can be loaded.

Route configuration looks as follows:

```
$routeProvider.when('/site/pages/:pageId', {/*configudarion*/})
```

In controller is code for getting page ID from parameters:

```
var pageId = $routeParams.pageId;    // when location is /site/pages/9 returns "9"
```

On the first load I get always the correct value of page ID. **Problem starts when location is changed via go forward / backward in browser (history).**

Then I start getting placeholder instead of real page ID:

```
var pageId = $routeParams.pageId;    // when location is /site/pages/9 returns ":pageId"
```

I tried to access `pageId` parameter also via `$route.current.params` and `$location.path()`.

`$route.current.params` returns object where `pageId` property is `":pageId"` and  `$location.path()` returns `"/site/pages/:pageId"`.

Why is the controller loaded, when the parameters are not replaced yet?

Comment: Seems like the browser is loading the data from its cache. I think the controller is not being instantiated again. All the data is being loaded from the browser cache.

Comment: Not sure about the cache. Tried it with caching disabled (google developer tools) and it happaned as well.